# Can Destiny 2 Cursing be Avoided/Turned Off?

Tags: destiny-2

Like the title of my question says, how am I able to turn this vulgar language off? It's rated Teen by the ESRB for three reasons, and I'd like to make it two.

Are there certain points where it uses this language, or is it spread out everywhere? I know if there's going to be communication with other players, then I'm going to have to turn that off (is that also possible?), but I'm just talking about everywhere in the game, can I find out where to avoid it, or is there an "off-switch" for this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't recall any specific instances, but depends on what you class as 'crass'. Swearing, curse words or specific themes of dialog? Are you referring to ingame chat or scripted sequences in the game?

Comment: @DavidYell Everywhere. I've found this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHQNqN9yEHg so text chat profanity can be filtered, but is this only for other real players talking to me.

Comment: Silly workaround I've used for a kid before: install it in a language you don't understand.

Comment: I guess you could review the game script? https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Destiny_2 I don't recall any swearing in the game at all.